# Node.js - How to export view to pdf

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pdf, html-to-pdf

I have a view that i need to export to pdf but to show this view i need to send a parameter to specific route and i don't know how to call route instead html file.

My route:

```
viewBicsDetails(req, res)
  {
    var ref = req.params.stamp;

    var info = request.query("query");

    var compounds = request.query("query");

    return Promise.all([info, compounds]).then(function(results)
    {
      console.log(results[0]);
      res.render('management-bic-details', {info : results[0], compounds: results[1]});
    });}
```

How can I export this render to pdf? i installed the `html-pdf` npm library.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf

```
 var fs = require('fs');
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
var html = fs.readFileSync('./test/businesscard.html', 'utf8');
var options = { format: 'Letter' };

pdf.create(html, options).toFile('./businesscard.pdf', function(err, res) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(res); // { filename: '/app/businesscard.pdf' } 
});
```

In `readFileSync` i should put the route.. but how?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1, with HTML and PDF templates**

Make pdf template and fill it with javascript code. HTML and PDF templates will be different!

There are a lot packages with this functionality. For example, [pdffiller](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdffiller)

**Solution 2, with single HTML template**

Under the hood [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) implements this approach.

1. Fill HTML template.
2. Render image via [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org) or any headless browser.
3. Compile image to a single pdf file.